# how to use copywith method by indefinite field name in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter application where I need to use the copywith method on different domains in different situations.

I will use the copywith method, I get the fieldnames from a constant
this is what i want to do:

```
MyProvider prv = Provider.of<MyProvider>(context);

prv.masterDetayTemp=prv.masterDetayTemp?.copyWith(
          data["fieldName"]:value,
      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad Solution:

```
      MyProvider prv = Provider.of<MyProvider>(context);

      Map<String, dynamic> newObj =
          prv.masterDetayTemp?.toJson() ?? <String, dynamic>{};
      newObj["${data["fieldName"]}"] = value;
      prv.masterDetayTemp = MyProvider.fromJson(newObj);
```